Why is the Google Cloud function not finding the default Datastore database?
I have set up a Google Cloud function that automatically runs a document AI processor when a document is uploaded to a storage bucket, and then sends the results to Datastore. I have created a database in "Datastore mode" called (default), but when I run my function, I get this error logged:
Error writing to DataStore. Here are error details
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="NotFound",
Detail="The database (default) does not exist for project
*projectID* Please visit
https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/setup?project=*projectID*
to add a Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore database. ")

I am not very experienced with Google Cloud (it is my first time using it) so please let me now what information might be needed to solve this.

The error is clear. Are you confident that you (a) created a database with the default name ((default)) when you created the Firestore database? (b) are using the same project (projectID) for both the Cloud Functions and Cloud Datastore?

You were correct about point b. I had used the project number and not the project ID. Changing it removed the error, but there is still nothing showing up in the database. I explained it further here.
